# When burgermenu is opened there is a shadow of which I want to change its opacity, but how?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, hamburger-menu

I am trying to figure out how to change the opacity or the box-shadow of the background of my burger menu when it is opened. I found this menu somewhere and I have used it at the portfoliosite I am making. Everything works but I want to make the content behind the opened menu fade by making the background of the menu less transparant. Also because then you can see that there is a round shape at the bottom of the opened menu, but now you cant see that.

So, when the button-toggle is checked the the menu opens and there is a round shadow expanding. That shadow is very transparant and needs to be less transparant in order to make the content behind it (portfolio pictures) less visible and the menu items clearly visible. But I cant find the way to do so.

I am stuck with this for a few days now and I have tried everything as far as I know.

Who can help?
Thank you so much!

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: rgb(35, 37, 43);
  font-family: "Roboto Mono", monospace;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  background-color: rgb(35, 37, 43);
}


/* nav bar styles */

@media only screen and (max-width: 414px) {
  a {
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  .nav-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    height: 10%;
    display: flex;
    /* margin: 0px auto 0; */
    padding: 0;
    /* padding-top: 12px; */
    padding-bottom: 12px;
  }
  .right-side {
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 0;
  }
  /* Hamburger navigation */
  #toggle,
  .toggle-container,
  .nav {
    visibility: visible;
    z-index: 4;
  }
  .left-side {
    position: relative;
    /* margin: 3px auto 0; */
    width: 100%;
    height: 620px;
    background-color: rgb(35, 37, 43);
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  #toggle {
    position: absolute;
    left: -100%;
    top: -100%;
  }
  #toggle:focus~.toggle-container .button-toggle {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset 0 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  }
  #toggle:checked~.toggle-container .button-toggle {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 550px rgba(235, 231, 231, 0.1), inset 0 0 0 20px rgba(248, 244, 244, 0.1);
  }
  #toggle:checked~.toggle-container .button-toggle:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 550px rgba(233, 220, 220, 0.1), inset 0 0 0 20px rgba(218, 214, 214, 0.1), 0 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset 0 0 0 20px rgba(238, 232, 232, 0.1);
  }
  #toggle:checked~.toggle-container .button-toggle:before {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg) scale(1);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg) scale(1);
    transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg) scale(1);
  }
  #toggle:checked~.toggle-container .button-toggle:after {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-45deg) scale(1);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-45deg) scale(1);
    transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-45deg) scale(1);
  }
  #toggle:checked:focus~.toggle-container .button-toggle {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 550px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset 0 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset 0 0 0 20px rgba(19, 18, 18, 0.1);
  }
  #toggle:checked~.nav {
    margin-bottom: 200px;
    pointer-events: auto;
    -webkit-transform: translate(50px, 50px);
    -ms-transform: translate(50px, 50px);
    transform: translate(50px, 50px);
  }
  #toggle:checked~.nav .nav-item {
    color: #ec7263;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    margin-top: 36px;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1, 1.1);
    transform: scale(1, 1.1);
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s, opacity 0.1s;
    transition: 0.5s, opacity 0.1s;
  }
  #toggle:checked~.nav .nav-item:nth-child(1) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.15s;
    transition-delay: 0.15s;
  }
  #toggle:checked~.nav .nav-item:nth-child(1):before {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.15s;
    transition-delay: 0.15s;
  }
  #toggle:checked~.nav .nav-item:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s;
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
  }
  #toggle:checked~.nav .nav-item:nth-child(2):before {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s;
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
  }
  #toggle:checked~.nav .nav-item:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.05s;
    transition-delay: 0.05s;
  }
  #toggle:checked~.nav .nav-item:nth-child(3):before {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.05s;
    transition-delay: 0.05s;
  }
  #toggle:checked~.nav .nav-item:nth-child(4) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
    transition-delay: 0s;
  }
  #toggle:checked~.nav .nav-item:nth-child(4):before {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
    transition-delay: 0s;
  }
  #toggle:checked~.nav .nav-item:before {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  #toggle:checked~.portfolio-items-wrapper {
    padding-top: 30px;
  }
  #toggle:checked~.portfolio-items-wrapper:before {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  }
  /* Toggle button */
  .button-toggle {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 46px 25px 25px 46px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 100%;
    z-index: 6;
    -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
    transition: 0.6s;
  }
  .button-toggle:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset 0 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  }
  .button-toggle:before,
  .button-toggle:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #ec7263;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    transition: 0.5s;
  }
  .button-toggle:before {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg) scale(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg) scale(0);
    transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg) scale(0);
  }
  .button-toggle:after {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-45deg) scale(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-45deg) scale(0);
    transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-45deg) scale(0);
  }
  /* Menu */
  .nav {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 46px 36px 20px 46px;
    pointer-events: none;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    transition: 0.5s;
  }
  .nav-item {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    color: rgb(115, 201, 194);
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: -5.7px;
    height: 9px;
    line-height: 7px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    white-space: nowrap;
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.2);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.2);
    transform: scaleY(0.2);
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s, opacity 1s;
    transition: 0.5s, opacity 1s;
  }
  .nav-item:nth-child(1) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
    transition-delay: 0s;
  }
  .nav-item:nth-child(1):before {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
    transition-delay: 0s;
  }
  .nav-item:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.05s;
    transition-delay: 0.05s;
  }
  .nav-item:nth-child(2):before {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.05s;
    transition-delay: 0.05s;
  }
  .nav-item:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s;
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
  }
  .nav-item:nth-child(3):before {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s;
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
  }
  .nav-item:nth-child(4) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.15s;
    transition-delay: 0.15s;
  }
  .nav-item:nth-child(4):before {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.15s;
    transition-delay: 0.15s;
  }
  .nav-item:nth-child(1) {
    /* letter-spacing: -8px; */
  }
  .nav-item:nth-child(2) {
    /* letter-spacing: -7px; */
  }
  .nav-item:nth-child(n + 4) {
    /* letter-spacing: -8px; */
    /* margin-top: -7px; */
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .nav-item:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    width: 150%;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #79d1e0;
    border-radius: 18%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) scaleY(5);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%) scaleY(5);
    transform: translateY(-50%) scaleY(5);
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    transition: 0.5s;
  }
  .portfolio-items-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    transition: 0.5s;
    top: 36px;
  }
  /* === */
  .nav-link-wrapper {
    display: none;
  }
  .brand {
    z-index: 2;
    width: 100px;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-top: 27.5px;
    margin-left: 190px;
    display: flex;
    line-height: 1.9em;
  }
  #LiaraLogo {
    width: 90px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    opacity: 0.75;
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: 6px;
  }
  .portfolio-items-wrapper {
    display: block;
  }
  .img-text-wrapper {
    margin: 0;
  }
  img {
    float: none;
    width: 320px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Mono:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<script src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js'></script>
<div class="container"></div>
<div class="nav-wrapper">
  <div class="left-side">
    <div class="nav-link-wrapper">
      <a href="index.html">Home</a>
      <a href="about.html">About</a>
    </div>

    <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" />
    <label class="toggle-container" for="toggle">
                    <span class="button button-toggle"></span>        
                </label>
    <nav class="nav">
      <a class="nav-item" href="index.html">Home</a>
      <a class="nav-item" href="about.html">About</a>
      <a class="nav-item" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="right-side">
    <div class="brand">
      <div>Liara Skara</div>
      <img src="Images/LiaraKleinformaat.png" id="LiaraLogo">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="portfolioPictures">
</div>
```

Comment: I transformed your code into a runnable snippet for your. Please make yourself familiar with this functionality before asking your next question. Now please edit your snippet so it demonstrates your problem, and remove irrelevant parts of the code.

Comment: Thanks for the transform! I pasted the snippet in my code but it looks like the shadow of the burgermenu is doing the same as before; when burgermenu is checked, the box-shadow that expands is quite transparant. But you are totally right, I should study more on box-shadows and transitions.